# React Native can't show date in ListItem from api response

Tags: react-native

Hello I have a problem with showing data in Listitem. I get data from api normally my api call url example is http://my-json-server.typicode.com/cagri90/DemoServer/Personeller . this.state.Personeller is shown in console.log but in List item they are not coming if I write perso rather than this.state.Personeller in ListItem mapping ,they are coming. I didn't understand Why is it not shown with state?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import {Headers} from '../layout/Header';
import {Get} from '../services/Dataservice';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'
const perso=[
    {
      "name": "Chris Jackson",
      "avatar_url": "",
      "subtitle": "",
      "rakam": "250₺",
      "islem": "Kalan Borcu"
    },
    {
      "name": "Amy Farha",
      "avatar_url": "",
      "subtitle": "",
      "rakam": "250₺",
      "islem": "Kalan Borcu"
    }
  ]
export  class Customers extends React.Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
        this.state.pers=[];

    };
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("---------------------------------------------");
        let urlparam=""
        Get('Personeller'+urlparam).then(personeller => {
            this.state.pers=personeller;
            console.log(this.state.pers);
            console.log(perso);
            console.log("---------------------------------------------");
        });      
    }
    render(){
        console.disableYellowBox = true; 
        return(         
            <View style={styles.container} >               
                <Headers message="PERSONELLER" />
                <View style={styles.list} > 
                    <ScrollView >
                        {
                            this.state.pers.map((l, i) => (
                            <ListItem
                                key={i}
                                leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: l.avatar_url } }}
                                title={l.name}
                                subtitle={l.subtitle}
                                rightTitle={l.rakam}
                                rightSubtitle={l.islem}
                                bottomDivider
                            />
                            ))
                        }
                    </ScrollView>
                 </View> 

            </View>
        )
    };

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:"white"
    },
    list:{flex:1,width:'100%'}
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `this.state.pers=personeller;` you should do `this.setState(personeller)`. You are not allowed to directly change the state of a component as you are doing here.

Read more about state in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: @Çağrı you also need to change the `this.state.pers.map()` to correspond to the newly set state. It would help if I knew what `personeller` looked like, but right now I'm just guessing.

Comment: I understood now. I have to say setState to refresh items in page.   this.setState({ pers: personeller}); solved my problem

Comment: @Çağrı Glad I could help, have fun!